# Breezejs projection not working for referencing one to many navigators

Tags: breeze

I have the following model:
1 Person to many Participant ('enrollments' is the navigator)

If I just want the name of the person, and the date of all enrollments, this doesn't work:

```
EntityQuery.from('Person').where('id','eq',id)
           .select('firstName, lastName, enrollments.dateEnrolled')
           .execute()
```

I get an error:

```
 Unable to locate property 'DateEnrolled' on type 
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[EntityClasses.Participant]'
```

What is the proper syntax for projections of fields on one-to-many relationships?

Comment: Have you figured out anything better than the suggestion below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no really good way to express this in a single query. You can get all of the "enrollments" but you will need to select out the "dateEnrolled" on the client.

```
EntityQuery.from('Person').where('id','eq',id)
       .select('firstName, lastName, enrollments').expand("enrollments")
       .execute().then(function(data) {
       // extract "dateEnrolled" from data.results
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a 'named query" on the server that performs the projection there and simply query the projection from the client.

Or perhaps better would be to invert your query.  Something like this: ( assuming you have a scalar property named 'Person' on your 'Enrollment' type).

```
EntityQuery.from('Enrollments').where('person.id','eq',id)
       .select('person.firstName, person.lastName, dateEnrolled').expand("person")
       .execute().then(...);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a named query?  Is it just a webApi server method that returns a collection of DTOs?

Comment: It is just a webApi server method that returns a DTO, for an example see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-depth ( the "Passing parameters to the server" subtopic).  But ... my last suggestion, to invert the query, is what I would really recommend, just for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have a number of relations to bring in, not just the one, so I believe the last suggestion is out of the running.  I will give the DTO option a try for this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working on my fork of breeze.server.net: https://github.com/eggers/breeze.server.net/tree/property-of-collection-25